# Html table creation probleme

Tags: javascript

i wanted to create an html  table using this function to generate a table . in order to test it if it gives any result i made a smaller test using numbers ( instead of my own data )  but it doest work.
here is my code :

```
function showFinalTable()
 {
      let finalTableHeading = document.createElement("h3");
      finalTableHeading.innerHTML = "Table finale";
      let table = document.createElement("table");
      table.classList.add("final-table");
      let thead = table.createTHead();
      let row = thead.insertRow(0);
      let headings = [
          "Process",
          "Arrival Time",
          "Total Burst Time",
          "Completion Time",
          "Turn Around Time",
          "Waiting Time",
          "Response Time",
      ];
      headings.forEach((element, index) => {
          let cell = row.insertCell(index);
          cell.innerHTML = element;
      });
      let tbody = table.createTBody();
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          let row = tbody.insertRow(i);
          let cell = row.insertCell(0);
          cell.innerHTML = "P" + (i + 1);
          cell = row.insertCell(1);
          cell.innerHTML = 5;
          cell = row.insertCell(2);
          cell.innerHTML = 7;
          cell = row.insertCell(3);
          cell.innerHTML = 8;
          cell = row.insertCell(4);
          cell.innerHTML = 15;
          cell = row.insertCell(5);
          cell.innerHTML = 13;
          cell = row.insertCell(6);
          cell.innerHTML = 17;
         
      }
     
  }
```

Comment: What is the result of your code? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

**You need to also `appendChild` the elements you create with `createElement`.**

Adding this line at the end makes it work: `document.body.appendChild(table);`

Full snippet, click "Run" to see output:

```js
function showFinalTable() {
  let finalTableHeading = document.createElement("h3");
  finalTableHeading.innerHTML = "Table finale";
  document.body.appendChild(finalTableHeading);

  let table = document.createElement("table");
  table.classList.add("final-table");
  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let row = thead.insertRow(0);
  let headings = [
    "Process",
    "Arrival Time",
    "Total Burst Time",
    "Completion Time",
    "Turn Around Time",
    "Waiting Time",
    "Response Time",
  ];
  headings.forEach((element, index) => {
    let cell = row.insertCell(index);
    cell.innerHTML = element;
  });
  let tbody = table.createTBody();
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let row = tbody.insertRow(i);
    let cell = row.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = "P" + (i + 1);
    cell = row.insertCell(1);
    cell.innerHTML = 5;
    cell = row.insertCell(2);
    cell.innerHTML = 7;
    cell = row.insertCell(3);
    cell.innerHTML = 8;
    cell = row.insertCell(4);
    cell.innerHTML = 15;
    cell = row.insertCell(5);
    cell.innerHTML = 13;
    cell = row.insertCell(6);
    cell.innerHTML = 17;
  }
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}


showFinalTable()
```